# How does the Catholic Church interpret "you are gods" in John 10:34?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospel-of-john

Jesus was blamed by the Jews because he made Himself God. So Jesus defended Himself by saying that is written in Ps 82 that 'you are gods'.

> John 10:34 DRB  Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, Ye are gods?
>
> Psalms 82:6 DRB  I have said: You are gods and all of you the sons of the most High.

It is interpreted that to whom Gods word is said may be called God. But how can you make clear that we are not God while God is speaking to us in Jesus?

Comment: You have made an error in that you capitalized the word gods in your question. Neither John nor Psalms has the word capitalized, which distinguishes the one true **God**, from lesser (man made)gods such as Degan for purposes of understanding the Biblical difference.

Comment: Do you know what the difference in writing is in Hebrew? Also only the capital?

Comment: Neither Hebrew nor Greek (at that time) had an upper/lower case distinction. All capital letters like this in the Bible are interpretations, and are often left out in modern versions.

Comment: And is in Hebrew a distiction between god and gods?

Comment: The Hebrew word used in Psalm 82 is *Elohiym* which can mean anything from God, god, angel,  divine ruler or judge, or simply one who is godlike. So the interpretation problem here is not the word used. It's why was this verse Jesus' response?

Comment: And also gods a suppose? And what is the RCC saying about your last question?

Comment: I'm sorry that my comment has upset you. Normally I do not even comment on questions about Catholicism but I was commenting based on the Douay Reims Bible. I was not aware that you were referencing any other Bible. Please disregard my comment or edit if you did not intend the DRB. If in the future you prefer another reference please quote the Scripture in your question, it will signal me and others not to use standard references. Best regards.

Comment: Well actionally I'm interested in any kind of bible but it becomes otherwise too broad they say. So no worry, you are welcome to post it here.

Comment: Please expand on what first you mean by the RCC, and secondly exactly what you refer to as my last question. I cannot respond when I am not aware of what you are referring to. Best regards.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is a misunderstanding of me. I actionally was talking to Joshua Bigbee, but I didn't watched very good that it was you :-)

Comment: I take no offense, but it will help if you will use the symbol and handle of the poster you are addressing. That is to use @ and the handle. Best regards.

Comment: @Marijn Everything I listed as definitions of Elohiym can obviously be put into plural form, as in any language. In these verses it is plural as the translators correctly made it. But it is common when talking of a word's definition to speak of the singular root word. I'm not sure what the RCC says regarding my last question. I'm saying that is really what answers to YOUR question should be answering. It's simple to solve the issue of the language, as I showed. It's more difficult and more meaningful to find out why Jesus quoted it in the first place.

Comment: God became man so that man might become God.

Answer (score 1):

The Catholic [*Haydock Commentary*](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id103.html), which collects the Fathers' and other Catholic scriptural scholars' commentaries, says for [John 10:34](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id103.html):

> **Ver. 34.** This is addressed to princes established to govern the people of God. They are the image of God on earth by the authority they exercise, and which they have received from Him. --- *Is it not written in your law,* (under which were also comprehended the Psalms) *I have said: you are Gods?* &c. Christ here stops the mouths of the Jews, by an argument which they could not answer, that sometimes they were called *Gods,* who acted by God's authority. *I have said: you are Gods.* (Psalm lxxxi. 6.) But then he immediately declares, that it is not in this sense only that he is God. 1st, Because he has been *sanctified* by the *Father,* which St. Augustine and others understand of that infinite sanctification, which he has necessarily by always proceeding from the Father. Others expound it of a greater sanctity and fulness of grace above all other saints, given to him, even as he was man. But 2ndly, he adds at the same time, and confirms what he had often told them, that he was the *Son of God, sent into the world:* that his *works* shew that *he was in the Father, and the Father in him.* by this they saw that he was far from recalling or contradicting what he had said before. And therefore (ver. 30.[39.?]) *they sought to* apprehend him, and put him to death for *blasphemy.* (Witham) --- *Eloim,* which name of God was so called from judging, and may be interpreted judges. (Menochius)